# How to match a formula in different level

Tags: replacement

```
Solve[4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0]
```

The result has many

$$
\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}
$$

so I want to replace them with a letter, for example , `t`.

So I

```
Solve[4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0] /. (1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) -> t
```

But return this(one of them)

$$
\left\{n\to \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-t-\frac{2}{\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}}\right\}
$$

I tried `//.` , `// Replace[#, (1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) -> t, All] &` , all can't meet my requirement.

This way is shorter.

```
Solve[4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0] /. {(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) -> t, 1/(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) -> 1/t}
```

But still need to write twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the expression contains both (...)^(1/3) and (...)^(-1/3) so you can do it with two rules:

```
expr = (1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]));
ToRadicals[Solve[4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0]] /. {expr^(1/3) :> t, expr^(-1/3) :> 1/t}
```

```
(* results: *)
{{n -> -(1/2) Sqrt[1/t + t] - 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/t) - t + 2/Sqrt[1/t + t]]},
 {n -> -(1/2) Sqrt[1/t + t] + 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/t) - t + 2/Sqrt[1/t + t]]},
 {n -> 1/2 Sqrt[1/t + t] - 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/t) - t - 2/Sqrt[1/t + t]]},
 {n -> 1/2 Sqrt[1/t + t] + 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/t) - t - 2/Sqrt[1/t + t]]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative simplification

```
Clear["Global`*"];

sol = Solve[4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0] // ToRadicals;

rules = {(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) :> 
   Evaluate[(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) // FullSimplify],
  (1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(-1/3) :> 
   Evaluate[(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(-1/3) // FullSimplify]}

(* {(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) :> (-1)^(1/9), 
 1/(1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3) :> -(-1)^(8/9)} *)

sol2 = sol /. rules // Simplify
```

[image]

Verifying the alternative simplification

```
4 n^4 + 4 n + 3 == 0 /. sol2 // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)

(n /. sol) == (n /. sol2) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

This keeps the solution purely numeric rather than converting it to a symbolic expression of `t`